# Your System is running on Low-graphics Mode

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I am using a dual-booting system with Windows 10pro and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I upgraded my nvidia driver in Ubuntu and set it to be used in the **Software and Updates** settings. The next time I tried to boot and every time since, I get a message saying

> The system is running in low graphics mode

and I can't proceed any further.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode" appears, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login with your credentials.

And then, run the following commands:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

Comment: It didn't work...no terminal has appeared

Comment: In order to arrive at the Terminal from the above screen, Start your computer while  pressing these buttons: CTRL + ALT + F1 and then enter your username and password before moving on.

Then Try these commands

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo reboot